# Should $(find package) evaluate on remote machine's environment?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a master launch file that includes two other launch files, one of which is contained inside a group like this:

```
<group>
  <machine name="machine1" address="hostname1" user="root" env-loader=/root/rosws/devel/env.sh" />
  <include file="/path/to/my/launchfile.launch" />
</group>
```

Inside launchfile.launch, I have another include like this:

```
<include file="/path/to/another/launchfile.launch">
  <arg name="myfile" value="$(find somepackage)/filepath/file.yaml" />
</include>
```

When I launch this system, the `$(find somepackage)` seems to be evaluated on the host machine, giving the wrong path for the package on the remote machine. I feel like any node launched within the group with that machine should find packages within that machine tag's specified environment. Is there a way to do that, or am I going to have to live listing the absolute path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277373/should-$(find-package)-evaluate-on-remote-machine%27s-environment?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2017-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-05**:
Have you tried putting the `<machine>` tag before your `<group>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @gvdhoorn:

> In addition to this:
>
> ```
> When I launch this system, the $(find somepackage) seems to be evaluated on the host machine, 
> giving the wrong path for the package on the remote machine."
> ```
>
> roslaunch always evaluates everything
> on the local machine, not on the
> remote one.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIR, you have to add the `default` flag within the `machine` tag in the `group`.
To quote [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine):

```
`default="true|false|never" (optional)`

Sets this machine as the default to assign nodes to. The default setting only applies to nodes defined later in the same scope. NOTE: if there are no default machines, the local machine is used. You can prevent a machine from being chosen by setting default="never", in which case the machine can only be explicitly assigned.
```

Otherwise, you'd have to assign the machine explicitely.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-06**:
In addition to this:

> When I launch this system, the `$(find somepackage)` seems to be evaluated on the host machine, giving the wrong path for the package on the remote machine.

`roslaunch` *always* evaluates everything on the local machine, not on the remote one.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2018-01-05**:
Thanks, your comment is what I was looking for. Can you add it to your answer so I can mark it as correct?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-05**:
I did not post an answer, only @mig did.

**Comment by [sacco22](https://answers.ros.org/users/45662/sacco22/) on 2019-10-02**:
Is there any way I can include a launch file which is stored in the remote machine? Calling a launch file (from host/local) and running it on a remote node is working but frequency transmission is slow. When I run the node directly from the remote machine the transmission has a normal frequency rate - hence it is not a network problem.